# Websphere MQ Connectivity from PHP/Linux using mqseries - Error 2035 - passing username

Tags: php, linux, ibm-mq

I followed the post at http://blog.phpdeveloper.org/?p=140 to connect to a remote WebsphereMQ from PHP / Linux using the mqseries extension and was able to get the connection working.

However, the request is being sent with the username of the apache user on the client and the MQ server is rejecting the messages with error 2035.  The only way I found to work around the issue is to change the profile under which apache is running to a username that has access on the MQ server.

Is there a way to pass a username when establishing connectivity to WebSphere MQ from php using mqseries?  Following is the code I am using to connect:

```
//define connection parameters
$mqcno['MQCD']  =  array(
                    'ChannelName'                   => $options['channel'],
                    'ConnectionName'                => "$mq_host_ip($mq_host_port)",
                    'TransportType'                 => MQSERIES_MQXPT_TCP
            );

    // Connect to the MQ server        
    mqseries_connx($options['qmanager'], $mqcno, $this->_conn, $comp_code, $reason);

    if ($comp_code !== MQSERIES_MQCC_OK) {
        die ("Cannot open connection to server $mq_host_ip($mq_host_port) : ".$comp_code. " " .$mq_server. " " .$reason. " " );
    }
```

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the PHP is just a wrapper around the C based MQI (see the instructions which talk about linking with mqm and mqic - the C libraries), and there's no way of supplying a username from the C client api, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We will be using the work around, and add the apache account as a local account on the MQ Server and grant access.

Comment: BTW When MQv8 GA's, if you have a password as well, you might be able to make use of the connauth stuff and adoptctx (See the end of http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q113250_.htm?lang=en ). Unfortunately I havent played with it enough to understand if it will give you 100% what you are after, but it might

Comment: Jason, might want to update this with the [exit](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q114370_.htm?lang=en) and other new v8 info.